# How can "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" be fixed?

Tags: php

I'm getting this error on my PHP page

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\brandista\wp-content\themes\brandista\front-page.php
> on line 86

If anyone knows about this error please let me know how to fix this. I need this to be solved.

```
<ul id="filters" class="blog_cat">

    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>

    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms("categories"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
    
        $count = count($terms); //How many are they?

        if ($count > 0) {  //If there are more than 0 terms
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
                // create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
            }
        } 
    ?>

</ul>

<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    query_posts(array('post_type'=>'casestudy','paged'=>$paged,'post_status'=>'publish'));

    if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div id="isotope-list">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

                $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "categories" );

                $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms

                foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
                    $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
                }
                ?> 
                <div class="blog-listing <?php echo $termsString; ?> item">  
                    <div class="test-img">
                        <?php the_content() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>
        
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add the same condition of `count` as `foreach($tersm...`. The array might be blank.

Comment: @Pupil Will you please help me how to do this as i am new in PHP

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing because, the array might be empty.

Please check if an array is empty before looping over it.

So,

```
if (! empty($termsArray)) {
 foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
  // .. Foreach code
 }
}
```

Comment: yes array s empty that's why it gives the error is there any way that if array is empty then it  will show in all categories